# Invalid method when extending template

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

Ive tried to override the `module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml` file and copied it to my `<theme-dir>/Magento_Newsletter/templates/subscribe.phtml`.
But after refreshing i get an exception:

```
Invalid method Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe::escapeHtmlAttr
```

Ive tried clearing my cache and manually remove cache directories but it still doesnt work.

I am using Magento 2.1.9

Comment: Try `static content deploy` command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`escapeHtmlAttr()`** is escaping methods added in magento from `2.2 version`.

I checked in `magento 2.1.9 magento version` newsletter `subscribe.phtml` file, this function was not used there.

If you check latest version newsletter module [subscribe.phtml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml) file, you will find this function.

Please check your magento version and installed modules/themes should be compatible with same version.